# Back again, need help fixing JS game

Tags: javascript

To be clear, this is a standalone javascript game to help me get more involved with the syntax.

At this moment I am trying to figure out a way to add a `list` function to list all of the things added in an array from that session(I am still learning how to implement this to be used with cookies and HTML).

```
//We name the functions.
function Person(name, personAge) {
    this.name = name;
    this.personAge = personAge;
}

function Animal(animalName, species, breed) {
    this.animalName = animalName;
    this.species = species;
    this.breed = breed;
}

function CreateYourOwn(creativeName, species2, power, customAge) {
    this.creativeName = creativeName;
    this.species2 = name;
    this.power = power;
    this.customAge = customAge;
}

//We list the arrays.
var Persons = [


];

var Animals = [



];

var Customs = [


];

function creator() {
    //I start the prompt to ask the user which one.
    var personPrompt = prompt("Welcome to virtual reality! Put in 'person' for person creator, 'animal' for animal creator, and 'custom' for custom creator! Or, if you want to list your creations, type in 'list'! NOTE: All creations will be deleted upon reload.").toLowerCase();


    //And this is where I am right now.
    switch (personPrompt) {
        case 'person':
            var name = prompt("Name:").replace(/['"]/g, '');
            var age = prompt("Age:").replace(/['"]/g, '');
            var person = new Person(name, age);
            Persons.push(person);
            break;
        case 'animal':
            var animalName = prompt("What is the name of your animal?");
            var species = prompt("What species is it?");
            var breed = prompt("What breed is it?");
            var animal = new Animal(animalName, species, breed);
            Animals.push(animal);
            break;
        case 'custom':
            var creativeName = prompt("What do you call this thing?");
            var species2 = prompt("What do you describe as the species as a whole?");
            var power = prompt("What can this thing do?(ex. shoot lasers, change eye color, etc)");
            var customAge = prompt("How old is this thing?");
            var custom = new CreateYourOwn(creativeName, species2, power, customAge);
            break;
        case 'list':
            var list_var = prompt("Which list would you like to view?").capitalize;
            switch (list_var) {
                case 'Persons':
                    for (var i = 0; i < Persons.length; i++) {
                        console.log(Persons[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Animals':
                    for (var m = 0; i < Animals.length; i++) {
                        console.log(Animals[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Customs':
                    for (var j = 0; i < Customs.length; i++) {
                        console.log(Customs[i]);
            }

    }
}
}

while (confirm("Would you like to make another creature ? (If you haven 't already, just click OK.)") === true) {
    creator();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your "arrays" are actually objects.

```
//We list the arrays.
var Persons = {
};
```

Objects don't have the `.push` method, that belongs to [the Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). If you want to use push you will need to make your arrays actual arrays.

```
var Persons = [];
```

Comment: I fixed that part(thanks!) but it still doesn't work! I can run a `while` loop asking if they want to make another person(which, in theory, would allow multiple things to be pushed if you keep on running it) but it still won't list the code when I run list_var.